# C# app keeps crashing at specific point, need help understanding problem signature

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, crash

I have a C# Express 2010 application that makes numerous connections to a hosted php script.  Once it gets to a point of around 7500 successful communications, the program stops working and offers this problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application Name: zz.exe
Application Version: 1.0.0.0
Application Timestamp: 4c8d6459
Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version: 6.0.6001.18000
Fault Module Timestamp: 4791a783
Exception Code: c00000fd
Exception Offset: 0002f1c2
OS Version: 6.0.6001.2.1.0.272.7
Locale ID: 1033
```

It is the same every time, and I really do not have a deep enough understanding to make much sense of this.  Google searches for the error and discussions regarding the ntdll.dll file were essentially fruitless.

One more thing as well, it is a 32 bit app running on 64 bit windows server 2007.  It can't be a native 64bit app due to the fact it uses jet.OleDB.

If someone could please offer some assistance in this matter I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you can obtain a stacktrace of where the exception occurs, please do so. Then examine it to find out where in the program the error happens. Then examine the surrounding code. Once you have a rough idea what parts of the code are likely relevant and what is likely irrelevant, edit your question and post the relevant bits.

Comment: Please show how you call the script.

Answer (score 6):

Your app has caused a stack overflow exception in the underlying Win32 subsystem.  Look for recursive functions or large local variable allocations.  Better yet, if you can attach the VS debugger to the app and trap where that error occurs, you should have a stack trace right to where the problem is happening.

Comment: How do you know it’s a stack overflow specifically?

Answer (score 0):

This won't really help, we would need a stacktrace of some sort, and even with that our help will be limited without sourcecode. If the program itself doesn't display an error, you might have more luck in the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was a matter of the method I was utilizing being recursive.  I changed the structure of the task to a threadpool, and it appears to have resolved this stability issue.  Thank you for the suggestions.